# Trading Post: Do goods have an expiry date?

Tags: banished

I store a lot of beef in my trading post. Do goods like beef or eggs or other food have an expiry date?

If not, can I use a trading post as an additional storage barn?
(I mean: Will vendors or traders also take goods from a trading post and bring them to the market)?

Answer (score 4):

There's no expiration date (yet) on food items, cattle, etc.

You can indeed use it as a storage barn, and even more you can use it to move stuff around. Stocking up on 1000 iron then unloading it will unload it in the nearest resource pile instead of wherever it came from, moving it closer to your industry if done right. And since the trader porters carry a lot more than normal laborers, it's a fairly fast process.

Comment: I'm pretty sure livestock still ages while it's in the trading post. There's a number of posts about animals dying before reproducing when they were left in the trading post for too long. I can't confirm this as I haven't left animals in there for more then the length of a season really, but it's worth keeping in the back of your mind when you buy livestock.

Answer (score 2):

No, the stored food - or anything else except livestock - has no time-limit or an expiration date.

I searched around for tips and found a person who did precisely what you suggest: use a trading post as an additional storage barn. I tried it myself, and it works like a charm, especially with food. So yes, do use it as an additional storage barn.
There's even one big plus thing to it, which also answers your last question: *nobody* but the trader will carry things around, and the trader will ONLY do so if you order them. (Meaning you have to set the desired amount of a certain food to more or less, depending whether you want the trader to bring stuff to the trading post or to the market.)
How is this a plus? Well, it allows you to micro-manage goods better.

For example, when there's a surplus of food, you can order a trader to bring a certain amount to the trading post and your people won't hoard it or eat it, because they have no access to it. And if there's some disaster or just a famine episode, you'll be able to tell the trader to quickly bring it back to the market, and voila, starvation avoided. Also, keep in mind that things in the trading post, much like people's inventory, don't show up in the tab with stored goods. So you can have a few hundreds of fish stored in trading post that won't show as food you have until you send them back to market.

I've been using this tactic for a while, and I think it's wonderful. :) No more starving hoarders.